# R: subset based on follow up information

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataset like this.

```
  loc followup area
1   a  m06     10
2   a  m12     20
3   a  m24     40
4   b  m06     10
5   b  m12     20
6   b  m12     22
7   c  m06      5
8   c  m24     40
9   d  m06     15
10  d  m12     25
11  d  m24     45
```

I want to keep each location only to have completed followup (including all m06,m12,m24). After coding the dataset should like this:

```
  loc followup area
1   a  m06     10
2   a  m12     20
3   a  m24     40
9   d  m06     15
10  d  m12     25
11  d  m24     45
```

which function should I use? Thank you so much

Comment: `df %>% group_by(loc) %>% filter(all(c('m06', 'm12', 'm24') %in% followup))` using `dplyr`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I forget to add "all" in the filter function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `subset` + `ave`

```
subset(
  df1,
  as.logical(ave(followup, loc, FUN = function(x) all(c("m06", "m12", "m24") %in% x)))
)
```

which gives

```
   loc followup area
1    a      m06   10
2    a      m12   20
3    a      m24   40
9    d      m06   15
10   d      m12   25
11   d      m24   45
```